# For loop convert While loop

Tags: java, loops

I'm java beginner and I'm working on a for loop and while loop. I understand how they work, but I couldn't figure out how to convert from a for loop to a while loop.

```
for(int row=rowIndex+1; row<this.getMaxRows(); row++){
   if(board[row][colIndex]==board[rowIndex][colIndex] && row!=rowIndex)
   {
       this.setBoardCell(row, colIndex, BoardCell.EMPTY);
       score++;
   }
   else{
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: See related questions at right -->

Comment: Here's another example to reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917164/convert-a-for-loop-to-a-while-loop

Comment: Strangely, no one asked this before, but, why do you want to do this again?

Answer (score 6):

A for loop is just a while loop with a variable declaration and a statement that gets executed at the end.

So this:

```
for(int row=rowIndex+1; row<this.getMaxRows(); row++){
   //body of the loop goes here
}
```

Is roughly equivalent to this:

```
int row = rowIndex +1;
while (row < this.getMaxRows()){

    //body of the loop goes here

    row++;
}
```

The only real difference is that the `row` variable can now be accessed outside of the `while`-loop. 
If you don't want to be able to do that, you can use another block around:

```
{
    int row = rowIndex +1;
    while (row < this.getMaxRows()){

        //body of the loop goes here

        row++;
    }
}
//can't access row here.
```

Comment: * "gets" is the correct spelling.
The two loops shown are only approximately equivalent, not precisely equivalent. The scope of 'row' in the 'for' loop is only the loop; for the 'while' loop it's the entire block in which the loop sits.

Comment: Good point! edited.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of a for loop is the initialization, then the check, then the increment. So:

```
int row=rowIndex+1; //first part
while(row<this.getMaxRows())//second part {
        if(board[row][colIndex]==board[rowIndex][colIndex] && row!=rowIndex) {
            score++;
        else
            break;
        }
    row++;//third part
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incomplete, but as per the information you gave, this is what you should have:

```
int row=rowIndex+1;
while((board[row][colIndex]==board[rowIndex][colIndex] && row!=rowIndex)){
    this.setBoardCell(row, colIndex, BoardCell.EMPTY);
    score++;
    row++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work

```
while(row < this.getMaxRows()) {
    if (board[row][colIndex] == board[rowIndex][colIndex] && row != rowIndex) {
        this.setBoardCell(row, colIndex, BoardCell.EMPTY);
        score++;
        row++;
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
```